# How to fix search box not working on Android for e-shop solution?

Tags: shopping-cart

i am using e-shop solution here https://obchod.life.cz but my search box does not for android phones and for Google chrome in case i minimaze the windows. For iOS, browsers etc working fine.

Any ideas please?

Solution of my problem.

Thank you.

Comment: If I show you the picture from a website and ask why is it not working, how on earth will you know why? Provide more context, show your code, etc.